# Response function not working sometimes for .ajaxSubmit()

Tags: jquery, forms, ajaxsubmit

I have called `.ajaxSubmit()` to submit data and after saving data successfully, upon response from server, I am redirecting user to next page using JavaScript. Issue is this redirect works most of the time but for 5 to 10 percent times it just displays the server response as text in browser instead of redirecting user to next page.

**UPDATE START**

One strange thing that I just noticed is that the page also gets redirected to the URL of form which is being submitted using `.ajaxSubmit()` means the server response displayed in browser has URL of form `action`.

**UPDATE END**

Please guide what is being done wrong here, why this random behavior?

Following is the code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function showResponse(data) {
        if (data.success == false) {
            alert(data.message);
        }
        else {
            var redirect = data.redirect_to;
            window.location.replace(redirect);
        }
    }

    var options = {
        success: showResponse, // post-submit callback
        dataType: 'json'
    };

    // bind to the form's submit event
    $('#signupForm, #mobileSignupForm').submit(function (e) {
        // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first
        // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);

        e.preventDefault();

        // !!! Important !!!
        // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation
        return false;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that in server side you are not getting proper format response in this 5-10 percent times. Try to debug and check.

Comment: Format of response is JSON in both cases, Firefox shows it as JSON in it's default JSON response window.

Comment: Have you debug the code server side to check if your request is not ending before it was suppose to end.

Comment: Yes, I am setting a variable for example `success = 1` at a single place on server side code and it's being returned properly.

Comment: If you haven't still figure it out. Send me both kind of responses.

Comment: **Response Headers:**
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers:`Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, 
    Authorization
    `Access-Control-Allow-Methods:`POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
    `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:`*
`Cache-Control:`no-cache, private
`Connection:`keep-alive
`Content-Length:`164
`Content-Type:`application/json
`Date:`Tue, 06 Mar 2018 18:01:24 GMT
`Server:`Apache

**Response Text:**
`{"success":1,"redirect_to":"https:\/\/www.examplesite.com\/cs\/1506\/page1?cid=15"}`

Comment: One strange thing that I just noticed is that the page also gets redirected to the URL or form which is being submitted using `.ajaxSubmit()`